# Rails scaffolding from scratch has its drawbacks

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, routes, scaffolding

**1st Question:**

I'm trying to make the create method work, but it appears that my form is sending data innapropriately to my DB. This is the server.log :

```
Processing Admin::AdminWysisController#create (for ::1 at 2010-06-22 13:43:58) [POST]
Parameters: {"commit"=>"save", "action"=>"create", "authenticity_token"=>"P8pW7GnSNr7RZcxFcejpfsu9YCX7z8hO0DJPH3rYalQ=", "controller"=>"admin/admin_wysis", "admin_wysi"=>{"post_published"=>"<p>\r\n\tstinky</p>\r\n"}}
User Columns (2.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
User Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = '1') LIMIT 1
SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
User Update (0.2ms)   UPDATE `users` SET `updated_at` = '2010-06-22 17:43:58', `perishable_token` = 'XMxt1yi5_4JEwPP-21GO', `last_request_at` = '2010-06-22 17:43:58' WHERE `id` = 1
SQL (0.4ms)   COMMIT
AdminWysi Columns (1.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `admin_wysis`
SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
AdminWysi Create (0.1ms)   INSERT INTO `admin_wysis` (`post_published`) VALUES(NULL)
SQL (0.4ms)   COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_wysi
Completed in 139ms (DB: 5) | 302 Found [http://localhost/admin/admin_wysi]
SQL (0.1ms)   SET NAMES 'utf8'
SQL (0.1ms)   SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
```

The most important part of that statement is this one :

```
"admin_wysi"=>{"post_published"=>"<p>\r\n\tasdfasdfasd</p>\r\n"}
```

Which should be just simply :

```
 "post_published"=> "<p>\r\n\tasdfasdfasd</p>\r\n"
```

Let's look at my view..

```
- form_for @admin_wysi, :url => admin_admin_wysi_path do |f|
    = f.error_messages :header_message => FORM_ERROR_HEADER_MESSAGE, :message => FORM_ERROR_MESSAGE
    = f.cktext_area :post_published, :cols => '70', :rows => '30', :width => '555px', :height => '240px', :toolbar => 'HQ'
    %br/
.grid_2.prefix_5.align_right
  = f.submit 'save', {:class => 'button'}
```

Here is my controller :D

```
def new
 @admin_wysi = AdminWysi.new
end

def create
  @admin_wysi = AdminWysi.new(params[:admin_wysi])
  if @admin_wysi.save
    redirect_to admin_admin_wysi_path
 end
end
```

Any idea what might be bugging this?

**2nd Question**

Strange as it is, when it saves, it redirects me to website.com/wysi NOT website.com/wysis/ . The latter one is a working  link, the prior is not a real link.

My routes.rb looks like this :

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resource :admin_wysi
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params you're getting are what's expected in a Rails app. Otherwise, there would be no good way to access only the parameters that are part of the object to the save (for instance, to discard the `commit`, `action`, etc. key/value pairs). What errors are you getting from the create action? If it's redirecting you, it seems like it is probably not getting errors while saving.

As to your routing problem, the reason you're getting the singular (wysi) rather than plural (wysis) is that you're using `map.resource` instead of `map.resources`. If you change that, I believe it should fix the routing problem.

Comment: thanks so much for your response. I made it plural. No worries there, that helped. Also, above I included the full SQL statement. You can see there are no errors, and the one I had originally up there is actually an accepted way to add data. Notice though in the statement this line <<<<<  INSERT INTO `admin_wysis` (`post_published`) VALUES(NULL) >>>> Interesting? Not sure what that means.. Anyways, thanks so much.

Comment: Haha..why would a default rails migration make a table cell null?

Comment: Turns out I had a attr_accessor :post_published in my model that made it so that anything written into that field ended up blank.